# AuthenticationFaliedException : Login Failed IMAP java

Tags: java, outlook, imap

When I am trying to connect to company domain email then I can but there is one more email id which is not shared mailbox but still I cannot connect to it. I was getting `AUTHENTICATE FAILED` exception the I putted in prop :
`prop.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable","true");`
then this error gone.
But after that I am getting now LOGIN FAILED error.
Below are my properties :

```
spring.mail.store.protocol=imap
spring.mail.imap.port=143
```

Code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", storeProtocol);
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.port", imapPort);
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
session.setDebug(true);
Store store = session.getStore();
logger.info("Store connection test.");
store.connect(host, userName, password);
```

Can anyone please help me on this to resolve this error.